# What does $\sigma(X, L(Y))$ topology mean?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I find in a book of O. G. Smolyanov, E. T. Shavgulidze. Continual integrals some theorem, where they use the so-called $\sigma(X, L(Y))$ topology. But there isn't any definition of this topology! Can anybode help me and explain what does this topology mean. More details: $X$ is vector subspace of vector space $E_1$, $Y$ - some subset of $E_2$ vector space,  $L(Y)$ is vector subspace, spawned by subset $Y$. Topological space is than $(X, \sigma(X, L(Y))$

Comment: Something  is missing here. Perhaps elements of $E_2$ are linear functionals on $E_1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy in the book there is a comment that they will often use that E2 is locally convex, and E1 is its dual (or vice versa). But in this theorem there is no such assumption (maybe, they missed out it).

Comment: If $X$ is a set and $M$ is a collection of maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (or more generally into a topological space) then $\sigma(X,M)$ denotes the smallest topology on $X$ which makes every element of $M$ continuous. I don't know how this fits into your setup but I cannot think of any other meaning for $\sigma(M)$.